# ViewModel variable not loading despite being update in onAppear function call

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am currently working on a fitness tracking app.

The app lets users add weights and calories eaten for a specific day, and then offers a view page, where users can see their entries, with average weights and calories at the bottom of the screen.

If I add a new entry, and then click on the list view page, then the new entry appears on the page, however the average does not get updated. It only gets updated if I go back to the main view and then return again to the list view screen.

```
struct WeightEntriesListView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var weightEntriesViewModel = WeightEntriesViewModel()
    var formatter = DateFormatter()
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack(spacing: 50) {
            Text("Calories").font(.title2).padding(.leading, 10)
            Text("Weight").font(.title2)
            Text("Date").font(.title2)
            Spacer()
        }
        
        List (weightEntriesViewModel.weightEntries) { item in
            
            let weight: String = String(format: "%.2f", item.weight)
            let date: String = self.convertDate(item: item)
            HStack(spacing: 50) {
                Text("\(item.calories)")
                Text(weight)
                Text(date)
                Button(action: {
                    self.weightEntriesViewModel.removeEntry(weightEntry: item)
                    self.weightEntriesViewModel.getData()
                }, label: {
                    HStack {
                        Image(systemName: "delete.left")
                            .font(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.title/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/).frame(width: 10, height: 10, alignment: /*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.center/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
                    }.padding()
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .background(Color.red)
                    .cornerRadius(40)
                })
            }
        }
        
        HStack(spacing: 80, content: {
            Text("Average Calories")
            Text("Average Weight")
        })
        HStack(spacing: 80){
            Text(String(self.weightEntriesViewModel.averageCalories))
            Text(String(self.weightEntriesViewModel.averageWeight))
        }
        .onAppear(perform: {
            self.weightEntriesViewModel.getData()
            self.weightEntriesViewModel.calculateAverages()
        })
        NavigationLink(
            destination: TrendsView(weightEntries: self.weightEntriesViewModel.weightEntries),
            label: {
                Text("View Trends")
            })
    }
```

The `weightEntriesViewModel`. has the average variables which get updated in the `calculateAverages` function. I am a bit unsure what the issue is, as the get data function seems to work well, as the new data is present in the list view, but the averages do not get updated until I leave the page and return again.

Comment: You did not share a sample of your ViewModel but are you using the @Published property wrapper on the properties you want to observe on?

Comment: is `self.weightEntriesViewModel.getData()` an asynchronous function?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
Button(action: {
    self.weightEntriesViewModel.removeEntry(weightEntry: item)
    self.weightEntriesViewModel.getData()
    self.weightEntriesViewModel.calculateAverages() // <--- here
}, .....
```